# The right way of using C#6 "using static" feature

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

How C#6 `using static` feature should be used in right way? It really looks nice for cases like shortening `string.Format (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Some format");` to `Format (InvariantCulture, "Some format");`, but is it always the case?

Take this for example. You have `enum` like this:

```
enum Enum { Value1, Value2 }
```

And you decide to to use it in code like this:

```
using static {Namespace}.Enum;
// ...
var value = Value1;
```

Latter on you decide to create a `class` named `Value1`. Then your code `var value = Value1` will generate compile error:

> 'Value1' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Or other case. You have two classes with different `static` methods:

```
class Foo {
    public static void Method1() { }
}

class Foo2 {
    public static void Method2() { }
}
```

And you use it in 3rd `class` like

```
using static {Namespace}.Foo;
using static {Namespace}.Foo2;
// ...
class Bar {
    void Method() {
        Method1();
        Method2();
    }
}
```

Which works fine. But if you decide to introduce `Method2` in `Foo` `class` this code will generate compile error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Foo.Method2()' and 'Foo2.Method2()'

So my question is what is the right way of using `using static` feature?

Comment: I don't see how `using static` is special here. You have working code. You introduce a new item that means that there is now ambiguity where it didn't exist before. You have to make your code more explicit. Exactly the same happens with non-static `using` when a new type is added to a namespace and the name of that type matches the name of another type in a different namespace.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So `using static` pretty much just creates a broader area for name collisions?

Comment: Obviously it is not when you confuzzle the compiler with it.  And sure, you *increase* the odds that identifier names are ambiguous.  It tends to work okay if you use one source file per type, a programming style that's pretty common.  Doesn't spin my propeller, but always follow your team's coding guidelines.

Comment: @Hans Passant if you're working with team that's one case. I'm interested if there are any general guidelines.

Comment: The general guideline is the obvious one, don't confuzzle the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problems" being stated were already present in previous versions of the language regarding type name resolution.

This feature just brings those "problems" down to type members.

Answer (score 2):

I've not read any recommendations on the topic.  But my opinion is that you can use `using static` for stuff that gives you names that makes sense on their own.

```
using static Math;

var max = Max(value1, value2);
```

In the case of `string.Format` I think it becomes unclear what `Format` means (all kinds of stuff can be formatted into anything that has a kind of format).